# Using word2vec to calculate sentence similarity

Tags: python, vector, word2vec, cosine-similarity, sentence

On a previous post I found some code that described a method for calculating the semantic similarity between 2 sentences.

My question is what libraries, modules, etc. (ex. from NAME import NAME) do I need in order to run this code on my computer.
[Link to code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35092200/revisions)

I was thinking maybe word2vec, numpy, scikit learn but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need is:

```
pretrained word vector
gensim
numpy
scipy
```

For the semantic, you need word vector so that you can calculate the similarities between your sentences.

Here is a step by step tutorial: [How to calculate phrase similarity between phrases](https://bitbucket.org/yunazzang/aiwiththebest_byor)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add the next imports to your code:

```
from scipy import spatial
from gensim import models
import numpy as np
```

If you are using *Anaconda Distribution* you can install gensim with:

```
conda install -c anaconda gensim=0.13.3
```

Remember that you're going to need some *model* in order to make a runnable code.

Comment: What do you mean by a model? Can Genism provide such a model

Comment: Model like this for example: https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors

Please consider learning what the code does instead on only make it running.

Comment: Some tutorial here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html
Hope it helps.